# Rollupjs Leave imports unchanged

Tags: javascript, import, es6-modules, commonjs, rollupjs

My input file looks like this:

```
import * as chalk from 'chalk'

const chalkInstance = new chalk.Instance({
  level: 1
})
```

My output file looks like this:

```
import { Instance } from 'chalk';

const chalkInstance = new Instance({
    level: 1
});
```

The problem is that chalk is a commonjs module and I want to my output to be an es module so when I execute the file I get the following error: `The requested module 'chalk' is expected to be of type CommonJS, which does not support named exports` etc. Is there a way to prevent Rollup from changing the `import * as something` imports? The problem doesn't go away even if I disable treeshaking.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Preserving the `import` as typed won't help you — you need to do `import chalk from 'chalk'` instead, since CommonJS modules only have a default export. If you *do* preserve the import you'll still get an error, it'll just be a different error:

```
const chalkInstance = new chalk.Instance({
                      ^

TypeError: chalk.Instance is not a constructor
```